# How to Send Emails in GWT Application

Tags: java, google-app-engine, email, gwt

I am using this code to send Email in my java application

```
        try{
            Email email = new SimpleEmail();
            email.setHostName("smtp.googlemail.com");
            email.setSmtpPort(587);
            email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("me@gmail.com", "mypwd"));
            email.setTLS(true);

                email.setFrom("me@gmail.com");

            email.setSubject("TestMail");
            email.setMsg("This is a test mail ... :-)");
            email.addTo("me@hotmail.com");
            email.send();
            System.out.println("Mail sent!");
            } catch (EmailException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Its working perfectly and i am receiving emails in my inbox, but when i put the same code in my GWT (Appengine project) server side,
It wont work
Its showing No Errors , no exception , and says mail sent , BUT it never actually sent to my inbox.

Also tried this

```
       try {
                Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
                msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("appname@appspot.gserviceaccount.com", "Example.com Admin"));
                msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                 new InternetAddress("myemail@gmail.com", "Mr. User"));
                msg.setSubject("Your Example.com account has been activated");
                msg.setText(msgBody);
                Transport.send(msg);

            } catch (AddressException e) {
                // ...
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                // ...
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Please guide me

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this: [Mail Go API Overview](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/mail/overview#Receiving_Mail)

And you are not getting an error because there is no error.
The mail is sent but you won't receive it due to the limitations mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code referred from [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail)

```
public String sendMail(String from, String to, String replyTo, String subject, String message) {
        String output=null;
        Properties props = new Properties();
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        try {
            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from, "Gmail.com Admin"));
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                             new InternetAddress(to, "Mr. User"));
            msg.setSubject(subject);
            msg.setText(message);
            msg.setReplyTo(new InternetAddress[]{new InternetAddress(replyTo)});
            Transport.send(msg);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            output=e.toString();                
        }   
        return output;
    }
```

By the reference from [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail), the sender address (`from`) must be one of the following types:

- The address of a registered administrator for the application
- The address of the user for the current request signed in with a Google Account. You can determine the current user's email address with the Users API. The user's account must be a Gmail account, or be on a domain managed by Google Apps.
- Any valid email receiving address for the app (such as xxx@APP-ID.appspotmail.com).

  I tried it and it works in a hosted *gwt* application.

Answer (score 0):

Implement this

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail

Comment: hi, thanks , i tried this but i am not getting any email in my inbox , edited my question , please look into it if i am doing something wrong

Comment: Have you also checked this: [developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail#Senders_and_Recipients](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail#Senders_and_Recipients) and checked the Spam folder of your mail account?

Comment: yeah i did , but can i only enter the address like :xxx@APP-ID.appspotmail.com,  because i dont exactly know my this address , how can i obtain this address

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting an AddressException and swallowing it without showing an error?

I ask because this is an unsupported 'from' address:

```
appname@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
```

It should be:

```
anything@appid.appspotmail.com
```

Or the email address of an admin or the signed-in user. See the rules here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail#Senders_and_Recipients

Answer (score 0):

same problem, this works for me, 100% works also for you (if you are using eclipse).

When you send mail, but actually it was sent to your localhost server. So you have to create your personal app engine from App engine administration console.

For that go to this [**Link**](https://appengine.google.com/) then select account that you want to use as to make your app engine, create application, than write application identifier (**Note this Application Identifier, after this worked in your eclipse project while deployment**)

Then in application settings, find this **Configured Services**, in that you have to give permission for your application, select your application language Java/Python/Go, after you will be redirected for inbound-services that you have to write in your web.xml

After from eclipse, right-click on your project, goto Google -> Deploy to app Engine, than write Application ID in Application ID field that was note down just before. First check you have to install app engine.

than click finish. It takes some time to deploy, than it will be automatically open your browser. So now your gwt application is on your server. Enjoy :)